# No voice output

Tags: java, speech-synthesis

I'm using VOCE library(https://sourceforge.net/projects/voce/) for speech synthesis in Java with netbeans for an application and below is the code.

```
public class synthesisTest{
public static void main(String[] argv){

    voce.SpeechInterface.init("../../../lib", true, false, "", "");

    voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize("This is a speech synthesis test.");
    voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize("Type a message to hear it spoken " 
        + "aloud.");

    try
    {
        String s = "Hey testing";
        voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize(s);
        voce.SpeechInterface.stopSynthesizing();
    }
    catch (Exception ioe)
    {
        System.out.println( "error:" + ioe );
    }

    voce.SpeechInterface.destroy();
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

However when I run this code the output is

```
[Voce] Initializing synthesizer
[Voce] Initialization complete
[Voce] Shutdown complete
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

but no voice output. However it is giving output if the string is read from console. How to fix this as I want this to work for the string provided in the code?

Comment: you stop directly after start maybe?! voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize(s); voce.SpeechInterface.stopSynthesizing(); put a sleep(3000) between these lines.

Comment: how?  voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize(s); is used

Comment: In the voce doc, for stopSynthetizing(): "Tells the speech synthesizer to stop synthesizing. This cancels all pending messages.
"

Comment: No use by putting sleep. Still no voice output

Comment: remove the stop line

Comment: From example on https://github.com/rpavlik/voce/blob/master/samples/synthesisTest/java/synthesisTest.java (the example you using no? most identical to your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call

```
voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize(s);
```

That starting the speech

```
voce.SpeechInterface.stopSynthesizing();
```

From documentation: "Tells the speech synthesizer to stop synthesizing. This cancels all pending messages. "

Then the speech is immediately stopped.

You must wait the end of the speech without forcing to stop it.
This must done in a loop else the application end before the speech.